# How can I add skew to any distribution (i.e. standard normal) in one direction?

Tags: distributions, data-transformation

What transformation, preferably an invertible one, accomplishes this? Thank you in advance.

I have come across one transformation. If X is our random variable, then `Y=sign(lambda)*X+exp(X*lambda)`. Unfortunately, this transformation doesn't add skew to just a single tail as I would like.

Comment: What is your goal? What do you know about $X$?

Comment: Hi. I'd like to be able to take a normal distribution and alter it s.t. a tail is fat. I woud know that X is normal- in fact, I am simulating standard normal data. I'd like to transform that data into such a skewed distribution.

Comment: If $X$ is normally distributed, you can always do something like $e^X$ to make it skewed, or $X^n$ for a positive $n>1$ (odd or even depending on what you need), etc there is infinite number of functions that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use the `scipy` function. `skewnorm` or as you can see in their documentation they are simply mulitplying the CDA with the PDF where `a` is the skewness factor.

`skewnorm.pdf(x, a) = 2 * norm.pdf(x) * norm.cdf(a*x)`

The complete documentation is found here:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewnorm.html

Comment: thank you for the reply.